# The DataTable's contains() method returns wrong value for Khmer language string

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datatable

I have a line of code in my application which is checking for the column, it is working well for English and Japanese language but return wrong results when the language is Khmer.

The column is not present in the  Table but it returns true.

The string for which it fails is as follow and sample code is as follow:
"លេខគ្រឿងបន្លាស់"

In my sample `WinForms` application There is one `datagridview` control and one button on button `click` following events occur.

```
private void btnAddColumns_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] arrColNames = { "លេខ", "លេខគ្រឿងបន្លាស់", "ឈ្មោះគ្រឿងបន្លាស់(THA)", "ឈ្មោះគ្រឿងបន្លាស់(ENG)", "បរិមាណ កំណត់ហេតុ/ SB",  "រក្សាទុកលេខ កំណត់សម្គាល់"};
        DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
        dSet.Tables.Add();
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < arrColNames.Length; i++)
            {
              if( dSet.Tables[0].Columns.Contains(arrColNames[i]) == false)
                {
                    dSet.Tables[0].Columns.Add(arrColNames[i]);
                }                    
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dSet.Tables[0];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

[image: Culture Info]

[image: T]

Comment: Please post a minimal and reproducible example. Otherwise one can only guess, eg. did you check the column names for the DataTable? Did you check the header text? Are you sure the text doesn't exist in the columns?

Comment: Check the contents of dSet.Tables[0].Columns and dGridView.Columns[i].HeaderText in the debugger.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, via debugging I have checked.

Comment: @JeroenHeier Yes, I have checked via VS2008 debugger, the column with  the specific name is not present but it still returns true.

Comment: So why does this test pass? `const string name = "លេខគ្រឿងបន្លាស់";
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   dt.Columns.Add(name);
   dt.Columns.Contains(name).Should().BeTrue();`

Comment: @stuartd  I don't know why it fails in my scenario, there is only one column  present in the datatable whose name is "លេខ".

Comment: Since nobody here is able to reproduce it you need to post a [mcve]. Most likely you will find the cause yourself while trying to do so.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yeah I think I have to figure it out by my self. :(

Comment: I did not say that :) You should try to create a [mcve], that exercise very often yields the answer, but if not then you should have something to post here that more people could try without resorting to guesswork on how things came to be. So try to create a small program that by itself exhibits the same problem. If that doesn't give you the solution, you can then post it here.

Comment: Dear @LasseV.Karlsen I have made the sample application and post the code, same problem in my sample application too.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], there's bits and pieces needed to be supplied to that code.

Comment: When reformatting that code I get a table containing 6 columns. Ensure your [mcve] sets the right culture as well, as I expect this might be involved.

Comment: For starters, could you try this and post the results? `Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name); Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name);`

Comment: Dear @LasseV.Karlsen I have executed the code and result is  attached in the image. :)